# Journey builder error 'Modified date'

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to test in journey builder and am getting this error - Submitted modified date does not match stored modified date. Please get the most recent version to update. To update an interaction, modifiedDate values must match.  anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I had to go back to the journey builder list and click on the journey again and re-amend then it let me save.